# PLS-00307 or does parameters order matter?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I could not understand this behaviour of Oracle DBMS. I have made two examples of PL/SQL type creation. First one is:

```
create or replace type TEST_TYPE as object (
    ID                      CHAR(36),
    NAME                    VARCHAR2(117 CHAR),
    IS_DEFAULT              CHAR(1),
    APPLICATION_ORDER       NUMBER(38,0),
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION TEST_TYPE(
        ID                      VARCHAR2,
        NAME                    VARCHAR2,
        APPLICATION_ORDER       NUMBER default 0,
        IS_DEFAULT              VARCHAR2 default 'N'
    ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY TEST_TYPE IS
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION TEST_TYPE(
        ID                  VARCHAR2,
        NAME                VARCHAR2,
        APPLICATION_ORDER   NUMBER default 0,
        IS_DEFAULT          VARCHAR2 default 'N'
    ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
        SELF.ID                  := ID;
        SELF.NAME                := NAME;
        SELF.IS_DEFAULT          := IS_DEFAULT;
        SELF.APPLICATION_ORDER   := APPLICATION_ORDER;

        RETURN;
    END;
END;

declare
   app TEST_TYPE;
begin
    app := TEST_TYPE(
        '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
        ,'APP_NAME'
        ,13
        ,'N'
    );
end;
```

Working well. But if you change the order of constructor parameters:

```
create or replace type TEST_TYPE as object (
    ID                      CHAR(36),
    NAME                    VARCHAR2(117 CHAR),
    IS_DEFAULT              CHAR(1),
    APPLICATION_ORDER       NUMBER(38,0),
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION TEST_TYPE(
        ID                      VARCHAR2,
        NAME                    VARCHAR2,
        IS_DEFAULT              VARCHAR2 default 'N',
        APPLICATION_ORDER       NUMBER default 0
    ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY TEST_TYPE IS
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION TEST_TYPE(
        ID                  VARCHAR2,
        NAME                VARCHAR2,
        IS_DEFAULT          VARCHAR2 default 'N',
        APPLICATION_ORDER   NUMBER default 0
    ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
        SELF.ID                  := ID;
        SELF.NAME                := NAME;
        SELF.IS_DEFAULT          := IS_DEFAULT;
        SELF.APPLICATION_ORDER   := APPLICATION_ORDER;

        RETURN;
    END;
END;

declare
   app TEST_TYPE;
begin
    app := TEST_TYPE(
        '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
        ,'APP_NAME'
        ,'N'
        ,13
    );
end;
```

This code will cause the PLS-00307 error. It's really wierd, because on live example where I have more VARCHAR2 required and default values I have to place APPLICATION_ORDER variable in the end to avoid following PLS error, but on this small example code I have to do the opposite. Could anyone explaing this behaviour and tell me how to avoid following errors in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating your own constructor with almost, but not exactly, the same signature as [the default constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_type.htm#GUID-389D603D-FBD0-452A-8414-240BBBC57034__BABGEFCH):

> The database implicitly defines a constructor method for each user-defined type that you create. A constructor is a system-supplied procedure that is used in SQL statements or in PL/SQL code to construct an instance of the type value. The name of the constructor method is the name of the user-defined type. You can also create a user-defined constructor using the *constructor_spec* syntax.

This also known as [the attribute-value constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADOBJ/adobjadv.htm#ADOBJ7414).

Your code works without defining your own constructor:

```
create or replace type TEST_TYPE as object (
    ID                      CHAR(36),
    NAME                    VARCHAR2(117 CHAR),
    IS_DEFAULT              CHAR(1),
    APPLICATION_ORDER       NUMBER(38,0)
);
/

Type TEST_TYPE compiled

declare
   app TEST_TYPE;
begin
    app := TEST_TYPE(
        '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
        ,'APP_NAME'
        ,'N'
        ,13
    );
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

... but won't pick up the `default` values if called with fewer arguments.

In your first code block you are defining your own constructor with a different signature, because the arguments (and data types) are in a different order to the default. When you create an instance using that constructor only one matches, because of where the `number` value appears in the list or arguments.

In your second code block you are defining your own constructor with *almost* the same signature as the default. When you try to create an instance of the type Oracle is able to implicitly convert the arguments you're passing to the types of the arguments of either of the constructors, and so it can't tell which of the two constructors you actually intended to call; and hence throws the PLS-00307 error, as the error message "too many declarations of 'TEST_TYPE' match this call" is correct.

You *can* override (or hide) the default constructor, [but the signature has to match exactly](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADOBJ/adobjadv.htm#ADOBJ7420):

> [...] However, a user-defined constructor does hide, and thus supersede, the attribute-value constructor for its type if the signature of the user-defined constructor exactly matches the signature of the attribute-value constructor. For the signatures to match, the names and types of the parameters (after the implicit `SELF` parameter) of the user-defined constructor must be the same as the names and types of the attributes of the type. The mode of the parameters (after the implicit `SELF` parameter) of the user-defined constructor must be `IN`.

i.e. you have to use `char` instead of `varchar2` to match the attribute types:

```
create or replace type TEST_TYPE as object (
    ID                      CHAR(36),
    NAME                    VARCHAR2(117 CHAR),
    IS_DEFAULT              CHAR(1),
    APPLICATION_ORDER       NUMBER(38,0),
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION TEST_TYPE(
        ID                      CHAR,
        NAME                    VARCHAR2,
        IS_DEFAULT              CHAR default 'N',
        APPLICATION_ORDER       NUMBER default 0
    ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);
/

Type TEST_TYPE compiled

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY TEST_TYPE IS
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION TEST_TYPE(
        ID                  CHAR,
        NAME                VARCHAR2,
        IS_DEFAULT          CHAR default 'N',
        APPLICATION_ORDER   NUMBER default 0
    ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
        SELF.ID                  := ID;
        SELF.NAME                := NAME;
        SELF.IS_DEFAULT          := IS_DEFAULT;
        SELF.APPLICATION_ORDER   := APPLICATION_ORDER;

        RETURN;
    END;
END;
/

Type Body TEST_TYPE compiled

declare
   app TEST_TYPE;
begin
    app := TEST_TYPE(
        '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
        ,'APP_NAME'
        ,'N'
        ,13
    );
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Now the default constructor is hidden by the user-defined one, so there is no confusion.